# How to smooth out a diagram?

Tags: algorithms

we have a data set that creates a graph, it works but the graph has many up and downs and looks really bad,

what I like to know if there is a known `technique` or `algorithm` or even an `API` that can smooth it out.

a very bad drawing of mine is demonstrated, so what I like to do is to get from A to B

I hope the picture below is able to represent what I try to achieve :/.

I apologies for the used tag, I'm not quite sure how to classify this question.

[image]

Comment: yes there is loads of them https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smoothing

Comment: Why is it that a jagged graph looks "bad?"  What information is the graph supposed to be conveying?

Comment: @jk. I feel such a fool mate, I don't know why I couldn't find stuff I wanted yesterday.

Answer (score 3):

To get you started, you should start reading about [Moving Average](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moving_average) which is the simplest smoothing method and is being applied to many fields ***outside*** signal processing because its explanation is perhaps the most understandable to everyone ***not*** having signal processing backgrounds.

In particular, all of the *Moving Average* methods belong to [causal systems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Causal_system), which means these smoothing methods *do not try to use tomorrow's data to calculate a smoothed value for today*.

However, if you have access to the entire time series (from historical data), then there is nothing to prevent you from using non-causal smoothing methods to calculate what you need.

(Aside from moving average, there is also another family of methods called "auto-regression", but it is often more used on physical systems, not artificial human-created systems such as economics and stock markets.)

Answer (score 2):

There are certainly a lot of algorithms for this. Probably the simplest one would be to change the value at every point to the average within x datapoints in the original.

Maybe not the best quality answer, but you can literally just choose from a list here: 
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smoothing#Smoothing_algorithms

Answer (score 2):

You can make a window function that takes weighted samples of adjacent elements and creates a second, smoother data set.  There are several popular ones.  Triangle, square (flat), Hann, Hamming, Blackman, Gaussian, etc.  Quite a few resemble a bell curve.  Each has a different effect on the signal.  The individual sample weights will always equal 1 so your average amplitude isn't effected.

You can then adjust the width (number of adjacent samples) to increase or decrease smoothing effect.  I.e. start with 5 total samples (-2 ... +2).  The wider the sample area, the smoother the graph.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Window_function

This isn't very hard to program or setup in something like Excel.